# Ill-behaved, nonnormal residuals of multiple regression: should I be concerned?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, residuals, diagnostic

I have data on waist circumference (cm) (waist), gender, age and physical activity (vigorous MET minutes per week) (PA).

I was trying to run linear regression in R on the model waist ~ gender + age + PA.

Gender was included because females will usually have a lower waist circumference then males.

Age was included because as people age their waist also tends to increase.

For physical activity, as this increases you would expect waist to decrease.

I was mainly interested in the effect of PA on waist and included the other terms in the model to control for gender and age.

Looking at a plot of PA vs waist, waist varied much more at lower values of PA then higher values.

Below is the summary call for my model:

```
Call:
lm(formula = waist.circumference.cm ~ Gender + Age + Vig.MET.mins.per.week, 
    data = FTO_data)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-20.167  -6.531  -1.600   5.020  49.900 

Coefficients:
                        Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)           74.5315680  2.3802320  31.313  < 2e-16 ***
GenderMale             7.8036918  1.2509220   6.238 1.14e-09 ***
Age                    0.1943671  0.0513102   3.788 0.000175 ***
Vig.MET.mins.per.week -0.0009486  0.0002635  -3.601 0.000358 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 9.944 on 396 degrees of freedom
  (128 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.1367,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.1302 
F-statistic:  20.9 on 3 and 396 DF,  p-value: 1.366e-12
```

These are the plots of the model.
[image]

[image]

Am I right to be concerned about the normal Q-Q plot and points that tail off upwards away from the straight line? Is this telling me that a linear model is not the best model for this data?

Is there anything from the Residuals vs Fitted plot that is concerning?

Is this model OK? If it isn't (as I expect) what steps would be recommended to improve it?

EDIT Graphs added by Nick Cox

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's MET? A couple of other points: (1) Why so many missing values? How might they affect the application of the model? (2) Aren't there enough data points to allow investigation of a curvilinear relation between waist circumference & age, & MET minutes per week?

Comment: I'd like to see plots of the distribution of waist circumference and vigorous exercise and a scatter plot of those two. I see two problems that are well-known facts but may be awkward for this analysis. Waist will be an extremely skewed distribution, as there's a lower limit for people to stay alive; your sample won't include starving people for obvious reasons; but it evidently does include some people with very high waist measurements. Also, many people do little or no vigorous exercise. Those facts don't exclude a linear model but your simple functional form has to struggle.

Comment: @Scortchi MET - metabolic equivalent of task. It's a way of defining physical activity and expressing the energy cost of the activity.
1) This is part of a bigger data set (n = 528) but only 408 participants have data points for vigorous MET mins per week and 519 had waist circumference measurements. 2) I was wondering if this would be a logical and correct thing to do and will try it.

Comment: You could post the data if they are not confidential. The selection problem here sounds serious, however, not that I have a good alternative. But it might not be outrageous to run a separate ultra-pessimistic model imputing 0 exercise where it's missing and see how different the results are.

Comment: For what it is worth. (a) you seem to have a small number of people with large waists for which the model does indeed predict a large value but not large enough. Do you have any other variables which might help predict them? (b) waist is a linear body measurement. Is that what you want to predict or would waist squared or cubed be closer to size? Just suggestions, not an answer to your problem.

Comment: @mdewey - (a) As well as vigorous MET mins per week I have moderate MET mins per week and walking MET mins per week. These three types of physical activity sum to give total MET mins per week. I also have scores from an eating behaviour questionnaire. This is split into three categories cognitive restraint, disinhibition and hunger. I would expect a higher score for disinhibition to be associated with a larger waist. I haven't added these into this example because I wanted to understand what this model showed first. But I will try adding more terms.

Comment: @mdewey - (b) waist is what I wanted to predict.  "or would waist squared or cubed be closer to size?" I don't quite understand what you mean here.

Comment: For some meaning of 'size' it is the volume which is important hence my thought about cube. But it was only a suggestion, feel free to ignore it.

Comment: 7 years late but .... no measurement for height?